# Would backtick in surname cause query to fail?

Tags: php, mysql, paypal

I have an ipn which runs a few db updates and writes a payment transaction. The ipn works fine. However, it failed this morning in the case of a person whose paypal surname was "O`Brien". (Note the backtick, rather than a regular apostrophe.)

In the ipn script, variables are like this:

```
    ...
$firstName  = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['first_name']);
$lastName   = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['last_name']);
...
```

.. while the insert query is like this:

```
$q = "INSERT INTO payments_log (`player_id`,`payer_email`,`transaction_id`,`paypal_first_name`,`paypal_last_name`,`payment_status`,`payment_amount`,`created`) VALUES ('$p_id', '$payerEmail', '$txn_id', '$firstName', '$lastName', '$status', '$amount', NOW())";
```

Other updates have run just fine, e.g. people whose surnames are "O'Sullivan", "O'Brien", etc, that is with regular apostrophes.

I can't find any other reason why the ipn would have failed other than the backtick. Can anyone tell me if that is indeed the cause of the problem? If it is, do I need to do str_replace on all surnames?...

TIA

Comment: The phrase "prepared statements" scream to me in times like this

Comment: @DarylGill it shouldn't be... Never encountered.

Comment: Since you're using mysqli, you shouldn't be doing manual quoting. Use prepared statements with placeholders, and then you don't have to worry about quoting at all.

Comment: .. I appreciate that, but the system is up and running (to allow kids pay a small fee to take an audition) and I'd *really* like not to have to take it offline and re-do it with prepared statements..

Comment: .. have just read up on, and run a few successful tests using prepared statements. Will re-do the script. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: @user2195707 excellent decision, prepared statements are the only solution that actually works.  Good luck with your project!

Comment: @CORRUPT Maybe so, but never trust your users input ;)